# OR-Tools CP SAT: global AddForbiddenAssignments on model level like AddAllDifferent

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have a list of variables and a list of possible assignments for each variable, that are added as regular AddAllowedAssignments(variables, tuples_list). This is simplified from my application, I do have harder constraints on this, but that does not contribute to my question here.

Example:

```
var1, possible values = [1,2,3,4,5]
var2, possible values = [1,3,4,5,6,7]
var3, possible values = [1,2,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I definitely need an AddAllDifferent(variables) which I can do on the model level like so:

```
model.AddAllDifferent([var1,var2,var3])
```

But then I also need some restrictions based on the values that exclude each other.
Example:

```
value [1] excludes values [3,5,6]     (1)
value [2] excludes values [5,7,9]     (2)
```

So I go ahead and create an AddForbiddenAssignment(variables, tuples_list) on variable level for each variable pair (I wrote the restrictions in two lines to make it easier to understand, but I know I can add them in one statement):

```
AddForbiddenAssignment([var1, var2], [(1,3), (1,5), (1,6)])     (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([var1, var2], [(2,5), (2,7)])            (2)

AddForbiddenAssignment([var1, var3], [(1,5), (1,6)])            (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([var1, var3], [(2,5), (2,7), (2,9)])     (2)

AddForbiddenAssignment([var2, var3], [(1,5), (1,6)])            (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([var2, var3], [(2,5), (2,7)])            (2)
```

That works fine.

I'm currently unsure if I need them in the other direction as well, but I guess so:

```
AddForbiddenAssignment([var2, var1], [(1,3), (1,5)])            (1)

AddForbiddenAssignment([var3, var1], [(1,3), (1,5)])            (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([var3, var1], [(2,5)])                   (2)

AddForbiddenAssignment([var3, var2], [(1,3), (1,5), (1,6)])     (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([var3, var2], [(2,5), (2,7)])            (2)
```

As you can see that creates a lot of constraints, especially when the number of variables increases. Creating all these constraints is currently a task quite poorly performing.

**Question:** Is there a way of adding the forbidden assignments on a model level like AddAllDifferent()? I would like to use something like AddForbiddenAssignment(forbidden_tuples_list) that does not need the variables.
Example:

```
AddForbiddenAssignment([(1,3), (1,5), (1,6)])     (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment([(2,5), (2,7), (2,9)])     (1)
```

Other option would be to have an AddForbiddenAssignment(value, forbidden_values_list)

```
AddForbiddenAssignment(1, [3, 5, 6])     (1)
AddForbiddenAssignment(2, [5, 7, 9])     (1)
```

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need integer variables? Why not use only Boolean variables, and sum()<= 1 and clauses. ?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to place strings. But since OR-Tools does not support these I have modeled them as integers. So the selected integer for a variable represents a selected string. Using boolean variables would only say that a variable is filled, not with what it is filled.

Comment: I meant can you replace an intvar by a vector of booleans with a sum() == 1? This will most likely happen internally anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how that would help. Do you mean something like one-hot-encoding? That would create even more variables, right? I have about 100 variables and 30000 possible values and about 10000 of above stated restrictions for the values. If I now create boolean variables for every assignment between variables and values I get even more variables and more restrictions, no?

Comment: Is your idea to do it like here with the NewIntVar(0, 1, 'x_%i_%i' % (idx, b)) on line 85? https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/samples/multiple_knapsack_sat.py
I guess my variable, domain and constraint spaces are too big for this. Creating that on the python side would be too memory hungry and time-consuming.

Comment: The other Problem I see is that I need too AddAllowedAssignments due to other restrictions. That's why I have bins with a bin size of 1 item per bin but that one item needs to reference a value from the domain space.

Comment: No, just one boolean for each var == value. Your problem is too big, but as I said, most likely the solver will create these Boolean variables anyway.